# what's the best place to save encryption public and private keys in a laravel server

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, server, gnupg

**The environment**: I have a Laravel 6.x application running on Amazon EC2 with Ubuntu 18.4 bionic, and Apache server. I have multiple scheduled artisan commands. They either generate files and FTP them over to a different server or, import a file from a different server. These files must be encrypted with PHP GNUPG before exporting them to client's server and require to be decrypted after downloading them from the client's server for further processing, therefore, there are public and private keys that must be stored on the server and in a way that the scheduled processes running as "Ubuntu users" can access and use them (I assume "Ubuntu user" only needs to have read permission on the key files, and no other user needs to be given any permission cause they don't and shouldn't be able to access these files, please correct me if I'm wrong). **My question:** I would like to know the best practices on, in what folder inside my server, and how (with what permissions), should I be storing these key files so I can assure they are safe, as well as making sure all automated processes will be able to access and use them as needed.

Comment: The answer here depends on the sensitivity of the data they protect. If you're storing healthcare data, you probably want a proper vault for secrets like https://aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/ or https://www.vaultproject.io/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Laravel` oauth package `Passport` saves them in the `storage` folder. Which is a good pointer to where `Laravel` dev's would expect them to be, adding a subfolder like `storage/keys` would probably also be feasible.

Permissions wise it is usually the standard to use `chmod 600` permissions.

Alternatively the `Laravel` env can save these keys [see](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport).

```
PASSPORT_PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<private key here>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. What is your opinion on saving the file in a keys folder inside config folder, and then put a reference to the address of the keys folder in the .env file? Do you think that's a good idea or is it even safe to do it this way? not that I don't like your approach, I understand that since your approach is the Laravel way then it most likely is following the best practices, I'm just trying to see how well is the approach that I was trying to take, Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not a fan, configs are generally a tracked folder in version systems. The benefit of storage is it is not, if you put it there and gitignore it, it won't hurt anyone. But i stand by that if you wanna keep it within laravel's folder structure, go for storage or env :)